# VUE: Refresh component on target route on push

Tags: vue.js, router

Im working on an info list.

- pages:

  - info - displays all data
  - info/add - add new data

so after submitting new data

I use `this.router.push()` to go back to the list.

my problem is the list on info page is not update.

what I want is to refresh info page after successfull submission.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: thats not the purpose of SPA applications if you want to refresh after you change route. you should use Vuex for an global store where your data dont get lost

Comment: Can you add code for your info component so that we can help you? Without knowing the structure of your code, its hard to say.

Answer (score -1):

do you get an error in the console? are you sending the information to some database or just updating the info component data property?

If you are sending the data to some service, then you have to retrieve the data again, sending a new request, you can do it in created or mounted hooks.

If you are just updating the data in other view, You could use Vuex to keep the state between pages.